# Python script Intermittently scrape nothing from webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from webpage using the following code. However, it only gives data one time when I run 100 times. 99 running output gives no data at the content. May I know how can I solve it?

````
from langchain_community.document_loaders import AsyncChromiumLoader

from langchain_community.document_transformers import BeautifulSoupTransformer

url = "https://shopee.sg/-BEST-SKIN1004-Madagascar-Centella-Hyalu-Cica-Water-Fit-Sun-Serum-SPF50-PA--i.322645596.19703489951?sp_atk=acf317ec-b869-41f9-b2df-99dca9054664&xptdk=acf317ec-b869-41f9-b2df-99dca9054664"

# urls = "https://www.espn.com"

# Load HTML
loader = AsyncChromiumLoader([url])
html = loader.load()

# Transform
bs_transformer = BeautifulSoupTransformer()
docs_transformed = bs_transformer.transform_documents(html, tags_to_extract=["p"])

# Result
print(docs_transformed[0].page_content[0:500])```
````

Comment: it works exactly once per 100 requests? consistently?

Comment: It is not consistently. But most of the time it doesn't give output. I don't know how can I solve it.

Comment: i would try and see what happens when it fails. print the first 200 chars of the html when it fails. see what it says. what's the status code, etc. it could be some spam/bot protection of some kind. although you are spinning up a whole browser so that certainly helps.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that website has many protections against scraping. Using your code and excluding selection of the `p` tag shows this is the entire html returned, with no `p` tags present:[image]

If you inspect the html manually, it clearly shows `p` tags present, meaning much of the website is loaded dynamically and cannot be scraped using your method.

For that reason, I tried to develop a Selenium scraper. In this instance, the page navigated to a login screen- which does not happen if you type in the URL manually- meaning they have protections against bots in place. I set up an email and password to allow Selenium to automatically login, but then I was taken to an error page. Notice the url has "anti-bot-tracking" in it, and it defines a CAPTCHA in the url but cannot be seen by the bot:

[image]

I tried the typical approaches to counteract anti-bot software, like a stealth driver and more natural mouse movements, but was not able to crack it.

So it looks like they are quite sophisticated in protecting against bots. You could perhaps use a more sophisticated tool, or find an incognito driver for Selenium, or maybe use something like Puppeteer, but it will certainly take some effort.